# FlatMapLatest with Replay

Tags: rx-swift

I have a situation where I have three observables that map to a result stream.

The first observable tells me which of two other observables I should take values from. On every emission of the first observable, the result stream switches to emitting the flatmap of the appropriate observable.

This is a situation that normally can be accomplished via `flatMapLatest`.

However, on every switch of the flatMap, I also happen to want to replay the latest stale value. This is an issue, because `flatMapLatest` does not provide for an ability for a replay on old values of existing observables.

See below for an RxMarbles of what I want to accomplish:

[image: RxMarbles]

I tried using `shareReplay(N)`, as in the code below, but that does not seem to solve the issue.

```
    let Observable1Replay = Observable1.share(replay: 1, scope: .forever)

    let Observable2Replay = Observable2.share(replay: 1, scope: .forever)

    let resultObservable = Observable3
        .flatMapLatest { boolValue in
            if boolValue == true {
               return Observable1Replay
            } else {
               return Observable2Replay
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are `observable1` and `observable2` cold or hot?

Answer (score 0):

When you are stuck, you can always roll your own and come back to it later:

```
func example(source: Observable<String>, obs1: Observable<String>, obs2: Observable<String>) -> Observable<String> {
    return Observable.create { observer in
        let lock = NSRecursiveLock()
        var last1 = ""
        var last2 = ""
        var isFirst = false
        var completeCount = 3
        let srcSub = source.subscribe { event in
            lock.lock(); defer { lock.unlock() }
            switch event {
            case .next:
                isFirst = !isFirst
                if isFirst && !last1.isEmpty {
                    observer.onNext(last1)
                }
                else if !isFirst && !last2.isEmpty {
                    observer.onNext(last2)
                }
            case .error(let error):
                observer.onError(error)
            case .completed:
                completeCount -= 1
                if completeCount == 0 {
                    observer.onCompleted()
                }
            }
        }
        let obs1Sub = obs1.subscribe { event in
            lock.lock(); defer { lock.unlock() }
            switch event {
            case .next(let element):
                if isFirst {
                    observer.onNext(element)
                }
                last1 = element
            case .error(let error):
                observer.onError(error)
            case .completed:
                completeCount -= 1
                if completeCount == 0 {
                    observer.onCompleted()
                }
            }
        }
        let obs2Sub = obs2.subscribe { event in
            lock.lock(); defer { lock.unlock() }
            switch event {
            case .next(let element):
                if !isFirst {
                    observer.onNext(element)
                }
                last2 = element
            case .error(let error):
                observer.onError(error)
            case .completed:
                completeCount -= 1
                if completeCount == 0 {
                    observer.onCompleted()
                }
            }
        }
        return CompositeDisposable(srcSub, obs1Sub, obs2Sub)
    }
}
```